# Is it possible to skip The Last Jedi and still make sense of Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, the-rise-of-skywalker

Having watched *Rise of Skywalker*, it's apparent there's not a lot of material in *The Last Jedi* that's actually relevant to the storyline itself. Aside from

> Luke's death/Force Ghosting

, which can be hand waved away (pun intended), is there anything else that is pertinent that happens in *The Last Jedi* which you need to know before watching *Rise of Skywalker*?

Comment: I think the better question is, is it possible to watch The Last Jedi and make sense of Rise of Skywalker. I contend that the answer is 'no'

Comment: Hmm. The fact that Leia was a Force User was pretty pertinent. Otherwise you'd be asking why Leia had a lighsaber and could train a would-be Jedi

Comment: I contend that there will never be a way to make sense of the final trilogy. The last 3 movies are all fatally flawed with poor plot lines and big plot holes. Disney doesn't care about canon consistency or even making sense. Disney only cares about making money.

Comment: I didn't see "Last Jedi" and only went to see "Rise of Skywalker" to be part of a large family holiday outing.  I did not find myself even momentarily confused.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It would certainly hurt comprehension a lot. Here are some questions I would be asking myself if I hadn't seen *The Last Jedi*, besides the ones mentioned in the other answer:

- Why is the Resistance all gathered on Ajan Kloss instead of their previous base on D'Qar?
- What happened to the galactic government? Is it gone after the First Order attack?
- Where is that Supreme Leader Snoke guy that I saw Kylo talking to?
- Captain Phasma was part of the trio under Supreme Leader Snoke with Hux and Kylo. Where did she go off to? Did she die in the trash compactor?
- For that matter, why is everyone calling Kylo Ren the Supreme Leader now?
- What is the Holdo maneuver mentioned near the end and dismissed as "one in a million"?
- When did Kylo talk to Rey and tell her that her parents were nobodies as she states?

Comment: Phasma was a bit part. Her absence is not notable

Comment: @Valorum - Phasma was part of the "triumvirate" under Snoke, in charge of the stormtrooper infantry. Her role in the first movie was not negligible (she helped get them into Starkiller base). So yes, her absence would be rather notable.

Comment: Given that they chucked her into a trash compactor, anyone who missed the middle film would assume that she died.

Comment: @Valorum - Because trash compactors have proven a reliable method of killing people in previous *Star Wars* films? Not to mention they didn't make a secret of her surviving in interviews and director's commentary.

Comment: The trash compactor in ANH would have killed them with ease had it not been for those pesky droids

Comment: I have never though Phasma as an important character. To be honest, now I have to look up and remember what happened to her. I think Phasma absence isn't that notable too.

Comment: As I recall, TFA established that the First Order was aware of the location of the Resistance's base. They were even charging up Starkiller Base to destroy it while Poe and company were running their attack. No need to watch TLJ to figure why they wouldn't stick around on D'Qar, waiting for the First Order fleet to pay them a visit.

Comment: @Adamant: Frankly, I was truly surprised/confused when I watched the movies and someone called "Phasma" showed up again, *because* I had assumed she was dead after being thrown in a trash compactor. With that said, I did perceive her as a token underling with a name rather than a character that is in any way important in their own right. That's the impression I got from watching the movie(s), without reading any behind-the-scenes material that explains what symbolic parts of which triumvirates she was supposed to have on the authors' desk.

Comment: Phasma was definitely marketed somewhat aggressively for TFA, so I definitely think she mentions a line here.

Comment: Regarding Snoke, one might conclude that the Emperor had emerged triumphant from a mighty lightsaber duel with him, and celebrated by stuffing his remains into a Perspex tube as a sort of trophy.

Comment: Do we have any reference that places Phasma on the same level as Kylo and Hux? Did she ever communicate directly with Snoke? I had always assumed she was just some random mid-level-manager who happened to be important because she was Finn's boss. Doesn't Hux refer to the Stormtrooper army as "his" army at least once? Wouldn't that place Phasma as some sort of underling of his?

Comment: Your list is kind of random. It mixes important plot points with really minor stuff.

You think that there exists a set of people who care about Star Wars enough to remember minor characters like Phasma and minor details like the names of planets and yet do not care about Star wars enough to watch every movie? Ajan Kloss? D'Qar? Who cares? Silvery storm-trooper lady? Who cares? "Holdo maneouver" reference is as important to understand as a New Hope watcher needing to know what a "Clone War" or a "Kessel run" is.

Having minor backstory mysteries is part of what makes Star Wars popular.

Comment: Your list is missing one tiny detail - Luke Skywalker.

Comment: @Zikato - That is because the other answer already mentioned it.

Answer (score 15):

There are a number of events that tie directly into Rise of Skywalker that would be baffling to someone who hasn't seen The Last Jedi

- Leia has Force powers. We see her using them in TLJ, then in the following movie we see her training Rey. If you didn't know that, it would be confusing as to why she can train a Jedi.
- Rey and Kylo are mentally linked, seemingly by Snoke. We see this beginning in TLJ, then a more extreme form in RoS. Without the previous film, they'd jump straight into this with little or no explanation.
- Luke's dead.
- Snoke's Dead.
- Although the Jedi books are little more than a plot device to get Rey to where she needs to be, without TLJ there wouldn't be an explanation of how she got them.
- We learn what happened between Ben and Luke and why the fledgling New Jedi Order failed so spectacularly. Without the intervening film we'd jump straight from "finding Luke" to "Ben having a mental breakdown" without ever seeing the cause.

That all being said, the middle film in this trilogy was eminently missable. Very little happens that couldn't have been glossed over in the scroller.

Comment: I would add "Why is the Resistance base suddenly on another planet?" "Where is Captain Phasma?"

Comment: @Adamant - They're always moving around. Not really much of a plot point.

Comment: They didn't really seem to until they were forced to by the First Order. It would have confused me.

Comment: Also, "Where on Earth is Snoke and why is Hux calling Kylo the Supreme Leader now?"

Comment: Having seen TLJ (but not RoS), I'm rather confused as to why Leia would be training Rey. RotJ I believe established that the force was strong in Luke's sister, so Leia being able to use it in later movies is hardly a huge leap. But Leia being a *skilled* force user capable of training others in its use is never established in any of the movies up through and including TLJ.

Comment: @TLJ - Sure, but in TLJ you see her using some pretty solid Force skills, not least the ability to fly through space like a latter-day tinkerbell

Comment: @Adamant : Snoke is on Earth?!?  What a plot twist.  I suppose we'll fly down to the one settlement on Earth and ask around to find him.

Comment: @EricTowers - Exactly! It's a great mystery.

Comment: I'd also add Kylo and Rey's relationship as well as the force bond. Without a lot of what happened in TLJ there would be very little reason for either to be as empathetic as they are toward each other

Comment: Btw. one might also note that some things seem to be easier to accept/understand without having seen TLJ, e.g. why would Rey seek out Luke when Leia could train her - seems like a waste of time. Or a waste of establishing that Leia wanted this to happen for Luke to regain some hope. @Dave This force bond stuff didn't give me any impression of them really being close, it seemed so *forced* that them being empathetic doesn't seem supported by it to me.

Comment: I agree with @8bittree, I went into The Force Awakens expecting Leia to be an active force user trained by Luke. TFA seemed to establish that she wasn't. The title of The *Last* Jedi also implies that Leia is not a Jedi, since I assumed that referred to either Luke or Rey. I always wanted Leia to be a Jedi, so it was maybe my favourite aspect of RoS, but it makes continuity worse, not better.

Comment: @Valorum The tinkerbell moment struck me as more of a "yep, Leia can indeed use the force," not so much a "behold! force grandmaster Leia!" event. It doesn't seem all that much more impressive than Luke struggling with his lightsaber in the wampa cave and Rey seems well beyond that. Are there other instances of Leia demonstrating substantial skill or knowledge about the force that I might be forgetting? If tinkerbell's the best you've got, then I'd think the little boy with his broom at the end of TLJ is just as qualified to train Rey.

Answer (score 9):

I really think this question is missing one thing - in what context are you going to watch *Rise of Skywalker?* As a casual fan, or someone really devoted?

And, more importantly - do you strictly mean to ask about it **making sense** - or, about every little detail being enjoyable?

There are many sequels or series of movies which - literally - would not make sense when viewed out of order. And, there are other franchises which a dedicated fan might find less enjoyable when one episode is skipped. However, in terms of your literal question of *Rise of Skywalker* making sense, I think the answer is pretty clearly **yes** you can skip *The Last Jedi* and it will still make sense.

If you're a dedicated fan, you may find yourself saying,

> Huh, I guess Luke died, because here he is as a Force Ghost

But given the pretext of handing the story off to a new generation, and the fact that we already lost a major character in *The Force Awakens,* that hardly seems to lack sense or even come as a surprise.

or,

> Wow, Kylo is in charge of the First Order and Snoke is nowhere to be found!

But again, that's hardly a surprise (and certainly wouldn't lack sense) given Kylo's aggressive, unpredictable nature and hunger for power.

So - while the other answers do point out many details that a dedicated fan might *wonder* about, I don't think there is anything in *The Last Jedi* that would be considered crucial to *The Rise of Skywalker* actually *making sense.*

And, further, it's arguable that casual fans may not even pick up on many of the developments that happen in *The Last Jedi* and, so, not only would *The Rise of Skywalker* still make sense, it wouldn't really be any less enjoyable, since casual fans probably wouldn't even pick up on things like,

> the fact that the resistance is suddenly headquartered on a different planet.

Answer (score 4):

**In a word, no**.

Most of the reasons that haters have been complaining about *The Last Jedi* essentially boil down to, one way or another, it having not been the movie they expected to see in some way they perceive as being strongly negative. Whether these complaints have any real validity can be debated up and down, and have been pretty much since the film's release. Some say that the movie needlessly subverted established lore and fan expectations for no reason other than shock value. Others claim this is just whining from fans who can't handle their pet theories having been shown wrong.

Regardless of the validity of the complaints, however, the fact remains that ***The Last Jedi* leaves the franchise in a very different state from where it was before**. Major characters are dead, some old, some new. Balances of power have shifted. Leadership of multiple galaxy-shaking factions has changed hands. Some would argue that long-held common assumptions about *physics itself* have been shattered -not merely the Force, but even deeper concepts- though this last is somewhat debatable. **Trying to go into the following movie with zero context as to what has changed is probably not a good idea**.

So my suggestion is that you ignore people telling you to skip TLJ completely and give it a watch. Develop a real opinion on whether or not you enjoy it, independent of what anyone else tells you, including me. If you enjoy it, great, if not, great, but make your opinion *yours*. Scripts are for movies, not for people.

Comment: This answer is inappropriate. *"others claim this is just whining from toxic fanboys who can't handle their pet theories having been shown wrong"* The OP wants an answer about whether it is possible to understand ST:TROS without watching ST:TLJ first. Your answer provides little informational content and a lot of editorializing about the intentions of ST fans.

Comment: My answer is no less appropriate than the question itself. I admit to editorializing about the opinions of SW fans, though I do try to present each side both as I believe a follower of that side would present it, and as an opponent would. But the question itself does the same, under a veil that's only slightly thicker. My treatment of the controversy is an attempt to provide information, not merely about the answer, but about the troll question.

Comment: @TheSpooniest There is a lot of assumptions based on why OP is asking the question and who is for what reason suggesting to skip the movie. The way it is, it's not an answer to the question, it's an answer to what you think is the reason for the answer based on your assumption about a group of people. So even that answer to another question stands on thin ground.

Comment: You assume too much about the OP's reasons and insert useless whining about supposedly toxic fanboys. Your answer is more of a rant then an answer

Comment: Your first paragraph talks about "the movie". Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @Geronimo Really, now. Ask yourself: who would even think to ask whether or not it would make sense to skip the immediate predecessor to a film in a series, itself in the middle of that series, and still have the latest film make sense? To anyone who hadn't already made up their mind to skip that film, the question doesn't even compute. This is a poorly-disguised attempt at manipulation and abuse of a platform intended to be used for asking questions in good faith, and I have responded in kind.

Comment: "Editorializing" which insults a group of people is not appropriate. I've edited out such insults. Do not add them back.

Comment: @TheSpooniest You seem totally trapped in your point of view bubble. Simple reason to ask this question is if you didn't see the middle movie yet and get invited to the newest instalment. Do you need to take the time to watch the other one somehow at home or can you just join in the fun? Pretty sure there are plenty of questions what movies out of the MCU one needs to see to watch a particular other one. At the very least these kind of questions do pop up in my real life all the time. Disgruntled fanboys of the kind you point out would probably suggest to not bother for either movie btw.

Comment: Even the _edited_ version of this answer is useless. It's still a rant and makes assumptions about other people's intentions. Just consider these lines. *"haters have been complaining"* and *"Others claim this is just whining from fans who can't handle their pet theories having been shown wrong."* and *" it having not been the movie they expected to see in some way they perceive as being strongly negative."* **I would downvote this twice if I could.** Can the mods close this answer or consign it to oblivion?

Comment: So much hate for my words calling out the TLJ-critics, and utter silence for my words defending the TLJ-critics. And you call *me* "trapped in [a] point of view bubble"?